# REGEX to extract multiple name/value tokens (vbscript)

Tags: regex, vbscript

Given a template that looks like this:

```
<td class="creditapp heading">{*}Street Address:</td>
<td colspan=2 class="tdaddressblock">
<!-- @template="addressBlock" for="buyer" prev="" @-->
     ^^ might be a space here, might not        ^^ always a space here
</td>
```

I need to read the name=value pairs out of the comment, plus the whole string so it can be replaced. Names could be any alpha-numeric with no spaces, values could contain anything except double quotes, will be short as possible, and will always be surrounded by double-quotes.

So, possible formats:

```
<!-- @pizza="yes" @-->
<!-- @ingredients="cheese sauce meat" @-->
<!-- @ drinks="yes, please" breadsticks="garlic, butter (lots); cheese" @-->
```

I've tried a dozen different variations, but the most successful I've been so far is to get the first name="value" pair and nothing else, or I get the whole page worth of stuff. So the desired matches are

```
[1] <!-- @ drinks="yes, please" breadsticks="garlic, butter (lots); cheese" @-->
[2] drinks
[3] yes, please
[4] breadsticks
[5] garlic, butter (lots); cheese
```

The closest I've come so far is

```
<!-- @(( |)([\w]+)="(.*?)")+ @-->
```

but it only returns the last pair, not all of them.

Comment: You can't do it this way. It's a 2 step process. Within a replace callback, match the entire comment `<!--(.*?)-->`. Each match grabs the  content, do another regex on the content. `\b(\w+)\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"`, do any manipulation, then write the content back to the original replacement. If you're using Dot-Net, use a delegate for the callback. If not, you need to construct the new string yourself within a while loop.

Comment: Note that if you are not replacing, AND using Dot-Net regex, you can use a _Capture Collection_ to get everything in a single match. Example:  `<!--(?:.*?\b(\w+)\s*=\s*"([^"]*)")*.*?-->` where the key val pairs are the group 1 and group 2 array[index] (respectively).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementation of the 2 step processes @sln mentioned in VBScript:

```
Option Explicit

Dim rCmt : Set rCmt = New RegExp
rCmt.Global = True
rCmt.Pattern = "<!-- @[\s\S]+?@-->"
Dim rKVP : Set rKVP = New RegExp
rKVP.Global = True
rKVP.Pattern = "(\w+)=""([^""]*)"""
Dim sInp : sInp = Join(Array( _
    "<td class=""creditapp heading"">{*}Street Address:</td>" _
  , "<td colspan=2 class=""tdaddressblock"">" _
  , "<!-- @template=""addressBlock"" for=""buyer"" prev="""" @-->" _
 , "</td>" _
 , "<!-- @ pipapo=""i dont care""" _
 , "rof=""abracadabra"" prev="""" @-->" _
), vbCrLf)

WScript.Echo sInp
WScript.Echo "-----------------"
WScript.Echo rCmt.Replace(sInp, GetRef("fnRepl"))
WScript.Quit 0

Function fnRepl(sMatch, nPos, sSrc)
  Dim d : Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Dim ms : Set ms = rKVP.Execute(sMatch)
  Dim m
  For Each m In ms
      d(m.SubMatches(0)) = m.SubMatches(1)
  Next
  fnRepl = "a comment containing " & Join(d.Keys)
End Function
```

output:

```
cscript 45200777-2.vbs
<td class="creditapp heading">{*}Street Address:</td>
<td colspan=2 class="tdaddressblock">
<!-- @template="addressBlock" for="buyer" prev="" @-->
</td>
<!-- @ pipapo="i dont care"
rof="abracadabra" prev="" @-->
-----------------
<td class="creditapp heading">{*}Street Address:</td>
<td colspan=2 class="tdaddressblock">
a comment containing template for prev
</td>
a comment containing pipapo rof prev
```

As Mr. Gates [Doc for the .Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9z80300(v=vs.84).aspx) method sucks, see [1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974619.aspx), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25222256/603855), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22453171/603855).