# Read file names into an array or dictionary for use as a user input

Tags: vbscript

I would like to have a script that reads a specific folder and extracts the base file names, removes the last two characters and then uses the result to populate the text of an inputbox. The user then selects from the given options and the remainder of the script searches and replaces text in a second folder with the selected text.
Example file names in the initial target folder:

> ABFA1
>   ABFA3
>   ABFA4
>   HVA1
>   HVA3
>   HVA4
>   ITALA1
>   ITALA3
>   ITALA4

Obviously, once the last 2 characters are removed, I am left with duplicates which I will need to remove.
Here is part of the script I have so far:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFilePath = objFSO.BuildPath(objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName("."), "\dwgs\logos")  
If Not objFSO.FolderExists(strFilePath) Then
  wscript.echo("Folder does not exist, script exiting")
  wscript.quit
End if
'
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder (strFilePath)
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
 strFile = objFSO.GetBaseName(objFile.Name)
  strFile = LEFT(strFile, (LEN(strFile)-2))
'   wscript.echo(strFile)           
    Next

'delete all duplicate files names and add result to dictionary (or array?)

'create an inputbox and present a number of choices populated by the dictionary/array

user1 = InputBox("Select a Logo:"&(chr(13))&(chr(13))&(*array/dict*)), "Logo Replacement Script")

' Set arguments
strFilePath2 = objFSO.BuildPath(objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName("."), "\dwgs")
FindString = "dwgs\logos\"
ReplaceStringWith = "dwgs\logos\"&(user1)

' Find and replace function
```

I am able to get the base file names with the last 2 characters removed, but I dont know how to weed out the duplicates and then use the result in an inputbox? (I'm imagining text within the inputbox of a number followed by a choice and the user enters the number to signify which option to use)
My first thought was to use an array, but after some reading, it would seem a dictionary approach might be better. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to figure out how to incorporate it into the script.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Updated script incorporating input from Ekkehard:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFilePath = objFSO.BuildPath(objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName("."), "\dwgs\logos")  
'
Function ShowFilesInFolder(strFolderPath)
    Set oFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolderPath)
    Set oFileCollection = oFolder.Files 
    For Each oTempFile in oFileCollection
        strTemp = strTemp & oTempFile.name 
        strTemp = LEFT(strTemp, (LEN(strTemp)-6))
    Next
    ShowFilesInFolder = strTemp
 End Function 
x = ShowFilesInFolder(strFilePath)
'
Function mkDic(aK, aV)
  Dim tmp : Set tmp = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Dim i
  For i = 0 To UBound(aK)
      tmp(aK(i)) = aV(i)
  Next
  Set mkDic = tmp
 End Function
'
 Dim a : a = Split (x)
 WScript.Echo Join(mkDic(a, a).Keys)
```

For some reason I cant get the mkDic Function to split the input from the ShowFilesInFolder Function?
Is there an easier way to go about it than what I have come up with?

Answer (score 1):

The VBScript tool for uniqueness is [The Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4(v=vs.84).aspx). This demo (cf. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45554988/603855))

```
Option Explicit

' based on an Array 2 Dictionary function from
' !! https://stackoverflow.com/a/45554988/603855
Function mkDic(aK, aV)
  Dim tmp : Set tmp = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Dim i
  For i = 0 To UBound(aK)
      ' tmp(aK(i)) = aV(i)
      tmp(Mid(aK(i), 1, Len(aK(i)) - 2)) = aV(i)
  Next
  Set mkDic = tmp
 End Function

 Dim a : a = Split("ABFA1 ABFA3 ABFA4 HVA1 HVA3 HVA4 ITALA1 ITALA3 ITALA4")
 WScript.Echo Join(a)
 WScript.Echo Join(mkDic(a, a).Keys), "=>", Join(mkDic(a, a).Items)
```

output:

```
cscript 45590698.vbs
ABFA1 ABFA3 ABFA4 HVA1 HVA3 HVA4 ITALA1 ITALA3 ITALA4
ABF HV ITAL => ABFA4 HVA4 ITALA4
```

shows, how to de-duplicate an array and how to stringify the (unique) keys for concatenating into a prompt.

Comment: Thanks for the input Ekkehard. Your function works perfectly when I use it as supplied, but when I try to pass the info via a variable, it doesn't seem to work as expected (and doesnt split the elements). i have updated what I have in terms of the script. Any further insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get a working script, but couldn't figure out how to do it without using a couple of temporary text files to pass the data on.
I thought I would post the code in case it may be of help to someone.

```
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8, N = 0
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFilePath = fso.BuildPath(fso.GetAbsolutePathName("."), "\dwgs\logos")
If Not fso.FolderExists(strFilePath) Then
  wscript.echo("The LOGO Folder Does Not Exist - Exiting Script")
  wscript.quit
End if
'
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("xtempLogos.txt", ForWriting, True)
Set objShell = CreateObject ("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace (strFilePath)
For Each strFileName in objFolder.Items
a = objFolder.GetDetailsOf (strFileName, N)
a = LEFT(a, (LEN(a)-6))
f.Writeline (a)
Next
f.Close
'
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("xtempLogos.txt", ForReading)              
TheFile = f.ReadAll
f.Close
'
Function mkDic(aK, aV)
  Dim tmp : Set tmp = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Dim i
  For i = 0 To UBound(aK)
      tmp(aK(i)) = aV(i)
  Next
  Set mkDic = tmp
 End Function
'
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("xtempLogos.txt", ForWriting, True)
 Dim a : a = Split(TheFile,vbcrlf)
 a = Join(mkDic(a, a).Keys)
 f.Writeline (a)
f.Close
'
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("xtempLogos2.txt", ForWriting, True)
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("xtempLogos.txt", ForReading)
theFile = f.ReadAll
number = 1
myArray = Split(theFile)
for i = 0 to Ubound(MyArray)-1
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("xtempLogos2.txt", ForAppending, True)
If number < 10 then f.Writeline (number) & ".........." & myArray(i)
If number >=10 then f.Writeline (number) & "........." & myArray(i)
f.Writeline ""
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("xtempLogos.txt", ForReading, True)
number=number+1
Next
f.Close
'
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("xtempLogos2.txt", ForReading)             
TheFile = f.ReadAll
f.Close
'
user1 = InputBox("WHICH LOGO DO YOU WANT TO ADD?"&(chr(13))&(chr(13))&(chr(13))& (theFile), "Add Logo Script", 11)
choice = (user1) - 1
wscript.echo myArray(choice)
'
Set f = fso.GetFile("xtempLogos.txt")
f.Delete
Set f = fso.GetFile("xtempLogos2.txt")
f.Delete
```